# How to refer parent resource in child resource when using terraform map (and for_each)

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, amazon-ses

I have the following code which works fine.

```
resource "aws_ses_email_identity" "main_from_email" {
  email = "some@email.com"
}

data "aws_iam_policy_document" "main_from_email_policy_document" {
  statement {
    actions   = ["SES:SendEmail", "SES:SendRawEmail"]
    resources = [aws_ses_email_identity.main_from_email.arn]

    principals {
      identifiers = ["*"]
      type        = "AWS"
    }
  }
}

resource "aws_ses_identity_policy" "email_notif_policy" {
  identity = aws_ses_email_identity.main_from_email.arn
  name     = "${local.namespace}-ses_main_from_email_policy"
  policy   = data.aws_iam_policy_document.main_from_email_policy_document.json
}
```

The above code is working fine.  But the email is hard coded.  I would like to have the (email) resources to be created based on some configuration provided in terraform.tfvars as follows:

```
clientemails = {
  "client1" = { "email" = "client1@gmail.com" }
  "client2" = { "email" = "client2@gmail.com" }
}
```

I modified main resource as follows:

```
resource "aws_ses_email_identity" "main_from_email_map" {
  for_each = var.clientemails
  email    = each.value.email
}
```

But, I don't know how I can modify "aws_iam_policy_document" and "aws_ses_identity_policy" to follow "aws_ses_email_identity".

How do I modify my terraform script to honor "clientemails" configuration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be relatively straight forward to do:

```
resource "aws_ses_email_identity" "main_from_email_map" {
  for_each = var.clientemails
  email    = each.value.email
}

data "aws_iam_policy_document" "main_from_email_policy_document" {
  statement {
    actions   = ["SES:SendEmail", "SES:SendRawEmail"]
    resources = values(aws_ses_email_identity.main_from_email_map)[*].arn

    principals {
      identifiers = ["*"]
      type        = "AWS"
    }
  }
}

resource "aws_ses_identity_policy" "email_notif_policy" {
  for_each = aws_ses_email_identity.main_from_email_map
  identity = each.value.arn
  name     = "${local.namespace}-ses_main_from_email_policy"
  policy   = data.aws_iam_policy_document.main_from_email_policy_document.json
}
```

Here, there will be a single policy which will allow all the same actions for all the SES email identity ARNs. To achieve this, since the SES email identity resource was created using `for_each` meta-argument, the `values` built-in function [1] was used to fetch all the values of the ARN attribute for all the keys (hence the `[*]` part).

There could be a way to modify the data source with `for_each` if needed (i.e., to create a policy per client email):

```
data "aws_iam_policy_document" "main_from_email_policy_document" {
  for_each = aws_ses_email_identity.main_from_email_map
  statement {
    actions   = ["SES:SendEmail", "SES:SendRawEmail"]
    resources = [each.value.arn]

    principals {
      identifiers = ["*"]
      type        = "AWS"
    }
  }
}
```

Then, you would also have to fix the SES identity policy:

```
resource "aws_ses_identity_policy" "email_notif_policy" {
  for_each = aws_ses_email_identity.main_from_email_map
  identity = each.value.arn
  name     = "${local.namespace}-ses_main_from_email_policy"
  policy   = data.aws_iam_policy_document.main_from_email_policy_document[each.key].json
}
```

The code where `for_each` meta-argument is used with the resources (e.g., `aws_ses_email_identity.main_from_email_map`) is called `for_each` chaining [2].

---

[1] https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/functions/values

[2] https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/meta-arguments/for_each#chaining-for_each-between-resources